# Photoshop script for turn on/off Only web colors in Color picker

Tags: adobe-photoshop, script

Goal:
Compare one color selected with eyedropper tool to foreground color (white).
If foreground color (f7f7f7) is close to white (ffffff) then run code...
I want to find/convert selected color to nearest web color.
If I turn on Only web colors in Color picker, then foreground color (f7f7f7)= white.
With a javascript turn on/off option for "Only web colors" in Color picker.

I have found only script which pop up Color picker:
app.showColorPicker()
[image]

Any ideas, please?
Thank you!